# Show line numbers in macOS SwiftUI TextEditor

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm creating a document-based application for macOS using SwiftUI.

Is there a built-in styling method for showing a TextEditor's line numbers?

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @Binding var document: AppDocument

    var body: some View {
        TextEditor(text: $document.text) // I removed a few irrelevant options.
            .disableAutocorrection(true)
            .font(.system(size: 12, design: .monospaced))
    }
}
```

The current view is the following:
[image: View]

Comment: You're probably going to have to wrap NSTextView to do this (or at least do this reliably)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, `TextEditor` does not have a method for showing line numbers.

You can confirm it yousrself following these two links.

#### TextEditor

*A view that can display and edit long-form text.*

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/texteditor

#### Appearance and Behavior

*Configure a view’s text, controls, and other content.*

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view-appearance-and-behavior